# how do I protect a folder with files in windows using a python code

Tags: python-3.x

I neeed to create a code with which I can protect any folder on my windows PC using Pyhton codem is this possible?
I've researched and on here I could file for Linux but nothing for Windows

Comment: Please add to the question what exactly do you mean by 'protect'?
Do you wish to make it read-only, only for specific users, hidden etc.?

Comment: Hi,
I need for the use to enter a password in order to open and see the contents of the folder.